# remove html component created dynamically when keyup event triggered

Tags: jquery, html

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="search buddy" name="search" >
```

this is a search bar all I want to do is that  whenever user types any character in the search a block must appear,  and as soon a the user removes all the character from the text box the block must disappear..so How can I implement this in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[id="search"]').one('keyup',function(){
        var text=$(this).val();
        if(text!="")
        {
            $(this).after('<div class="panel" id="search_results">hello</div>');
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: yes I want to make that div appear only for one time ..but how to remove it

Comment: why do you not just show/hide it? Also can check if it exists inside `on()`

Comment: @hatim `yes I want to make that div appear only for one time ..but how to remove it` ► When using `one` the binding is removed after first execution. This also means you cannot remove the `div` or show it again when needed. You will have to leave the `keyup` binding in place as you want to continuously interrogate the text to show/hide the `div` as needed. Hence you need to use `on`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want. To remove an element you just select an element and call `.remove()`. This snippet also makes it so that there is only one `#search_result` at once.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[id="search"]').on('input',function(){
        var text=$(this).val();
        $('#search_results').remove()
        if(text!="") {
          $(this).after('<div class="panel" id="search_results">hello</div>');
        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="search buddy" name="search" >
```

Comment: Works. Now the next challenge: also making it work on mouse right click -> Paste, and also Cut :-)

Comment: this code is making <div> to appear multiple times when we are pressing the key..and also it should hide when text box does not have any character in it

Comment: Try the snippet again, the div is not appearing multiple times for me and it does hide when there is no character.